# updating in pandas dataframe in multithreading fashion

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency

I have a datfarme of size 10000000X70, I have to update some values in this dataframe(BIG_DF) based on values from samller_DB. In single threaded it is possible however it is really slow. What I did, was created a multithreaded instance to update BIG_DF i.e.

```
 with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=AMEND_DB.shape[0]) as executor:
        for i,r in samller_DB.iterrows():
            executor.submit(update_DF, r)

def update_DF(r) -> pd.DataFrame:   
  BIG_DF.loc[(BIG_DF.index.get_level_values('ID1')==r['ID1'])&(BIG_DF.index.get_level_values('ID2')==r['ID2']),[r['column']]]= r['value']
```

Problem with this Approach is that I some I'm able to update the BIG_DF and other times I'm not, i.e it is random. I have also tried ProcessPoolExecutor and it is slower than ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: You have race conditions.  Multithreading will not help you here.

Comment: @MikeRobinson, Well I'm not sure if there should be a race condition here, as I specifically Change value at given 'index' only.